# A Sliding Goodness of Fit Method? (Foray into the Stats Community Wielding only R-Squared)

Tags: goodness-of-fit, moving-window

I am a bit of a Stats idiot.

I have two waveforms that I want to compare. One is an actual measurement, the other is a model of the first waveform which I calculate by convolving an impulse response function with an input.

So far I have been analyzing how well my model fits my measurement by calculating r squared. I'd like to view how well the model fits the measurement as more of a time series though. I'm suspicious that the model fits well during certain portions of the trial and totally breaks down during others.

My intuition was to create a kind of sliding window of R-squared values, but like I said I'm kind of statistically challenged :) so every problem looks like a nail that I can hammer with my R-squared hammer.

My questions are, first, is a sliding r-squared kosher? (Haven't found anything of the sort in my brief literature searches). Second, can anyone provide reference to a better method? Just enough to get me on the right path is sufficient.

Thanks again for any help. If you could provide any reference to support your answer, that would be doubly helpful.